# Set the date in the ui.calendar

Tags: java, date, user-interface, calendar, webix

Is there a way to set the start date/select it programmatically in the Webix calendar?

I found only two methods, both seems unsatisfying.

- `date` property which, as far as I can see, shows only the initial year and month, but not the day. Date object is still `'null'`.
- `calendar.selectDate(new Date(year, month, day))` is almost what I expect: Date object is ok and the right day is selected.

But. There's no redirect from the current month to the selected one - select stays invisible for users.

Have I missed something? Is there really a way to select a date and see it?

Here's a basic code and the [snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/5e03b7ef):

```
var calendar = webix.ui({    
  view:"calendar",        
  date:new Date(2015,3,16) //months start from 0
});

calendar.selectDate(new Date(2016,3,25)); 

console.log(calendar.getSelectedDate())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that

```
calendar.selectDate(new Date(2016,4,25), true); //has a second boolean parameter for showing the selected date
```

and

```
calendar.setValue(new Date(2016,4,25));
```

do the job.

[**Snippet**](http://webix.com/snippet/21369fbb)